# When I use sqlite3.connect('database_name.db'), how is Connection object made even when we do not explicitly specify the class name, Connection?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

`import sqlite3`
`conn=sqlite3.connect('jobs.db')`

When the above lines are executed, we find that `conn` is an object of `Connection` class, which is present in sqlite3 python module.

The description of `conn` is as follows:

`conn Connection (<class 'sqlite3.Connection'>)`
`<sqlite3.Connection at 0x7fe12f6f3490>`

Even though we did not explicitly specify in the code that `conn` is a `Connection` object, how does the interpreter determine that `connect()` is a function present in `Connection` class inside the module, and a `Connection` object must be prepared?

Comment: `connect()` is NOT a method of the `Connection` class. It's a module-level function which instantiates and returns a `Connection` object. Nothing magic here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection) of sqlite3, we find that it mentions,

*Opens a connection to the SQLite database file database. By default returns a Connection object, unless a custom factory is given.*

Therefore, the developers have made this the default setting. You can however, provide your own custom factory.